# How to use multiple annotation with filter in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have use below code for getting result but always get same output for total_deal and total_coupons. I dont know what is happening in this code.

```
total_coupons = Count('coupon', filter=Q(coupon__is_sale__lte=0))
total_deals = Count('coupon', filter=Q(coupon__is_sale__gt=0))

queryset = coupon.objects.values('store_id','store_name','store_site','affiliate_url').annotate(total_deals=total_deals, total_coupons=total_coupons)
```

So how can write a query so its give me below outcome?

```
store_id  store_name store_site affiliate_url total_coupons total_deals
1         abc        abc.com    anything       5             3         (totsl is 8)
```

Is there anyway to get above output ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, `annotate(total_deals=total_deals).annotate(total_coupons=total_coupons)` not `.annotate(total_deals=total_deals, total_coupons=total_coupons)`

```
queryset = coupon.objects.values('store_id','store_name','store_site','affiliate_url').annotate(total_deals=total_deals).annotate(total_coupons=total_coupons)
```

Comment: I tried this it give me addition of both (total_deals+total_coupons) but I want individual count with ('store_id','store_name','store_site','affiliate_url') field

Comment: add 'total_deals' and 'total_coupons' to values.example: `xxx.values('store_id','store_name','store_site','affiliate_url', 'total_deals', 'total_coupons').xxx`

Comment: when I add it gives me error:                                                
 FieldError("Cannot resolve keyword u'total_deals' into field. Choices are: affiliate_url, brand_id, country_code, coupon, created, guid, is_footer_popular_store, is_home_page_featured, is_sidebar_top_store, is_store_popular, is_top_megamenu_store, pendingcoupon, store_description, store_heading, store_id, store_image_path, store_meta_content, store_name, store_short_description, store_site, store_title, store_url, storerating, subscriber, updated, updated_by",) is not JSON serializable